# rails3 shortcut

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Previously I used to do

```
project = Project.find_by_name('foo')
```

Now rails3 has better syntax so I started using

```
project = Project.where(:name => 'foo').limit(1).first
```

However this new style is too verbose. Is there a shortcut I should know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one should still work. Does it not?

Comment: Have you determined that it's a bottleneck in your app? Have you profiled it?

Comment: Seems like it would be a minor in the overall scope of your app.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `.limit(1)` is redundant; calling the `.first` method already does this for you. Like the other answer mentions, the first style should still work perfectly fine and is not deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

how about using a named scope?

```
scope :find_foo, where(:name => 'foo').limit(1).first
```

then just do

```
Project.find_foo
```

of course you can make it dynamic using lambda

http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just

```
project = Project.where(:name => 'foo')
```

You didn't have a limit on the find_by_name so I assume names are unique.

Comment: `find_by_name` always returns just one record, even if you don't have unique names. If you wanted all names, you'd have to do `find_all_by_name`.

Comment: project = Project.where(:name => 'foo').first, still no need for limit

Comment: `Project.where(:name => 'foo').first` then :)